# Як перекласти англійське слово «clickbait»?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english, неологізми

Зараз дедалі актуальним і поширеним стає англійський неологізм **«clickbait»**. В інтернеті кожен з цим стикався: ним називають якусь провокативну чи інтригуючу сутність (заголовок, текст, картинка, фото), основна мета якої – привернути увагу користувача, щоб він здійснив перехід по посиланню (тобто, «клікнув»).

Утворене сполученням двох слів:

- **«click/клік»** (власне те, що вимагається від читача: клікнути – відвідати сайт);
- та **«bait/приманка»** (короткий текст чи картинка характерного змісту).

Найпростіший спосіб – транскрипція **«клікбейт»**. Вона вже поширюється в  українському сегменті: [45 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82) google (мінус один азербайджанський сайт російською). Пошук по **«клік-бейт»** дає більше результатів, але це суміш українських, болгарських і російських сайтів.

Передбачаючи дедалі більше поширення цього слова, можливо, є кращий спосіб передати його суть українською? І людина, яка не ознайомлена із інтернет-термінологією, розуміла, що  мається на  увазі.

---

1. [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clickbait)
2. [The Rice University Neologisms Database](http://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=17374)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кліколовка - як мишоловка, тільки для кліків.

Якщо перекласти "клік" як "клац" то буде вже клацоловка.